# FileSystemWatcher: System.IO.IOException ("File used by another process")

Tags: c#, ioexception, filesystemwatcher

Currently i'm working on an application, that should watch a specific directory for changes (say a new file was created) and then in turn upload the file to Sharepoint. Thatfore i'm using the FileSystemWatcher class which throws an event with the path to the created file, which in turn i use in another method to upload the file. The problem is: While in debug mode in Visual Studio i realized that the first file i create in the watched directory gets uploaded perfectly, even if i drag multiple files into the directory at once all are uploaded, BUT when i do it one file after another i get an exception that the second file is already in use. So i drag File1.txt into the directory, it works, but then, when i drag file2.txt into the directory right after i get a System.IO.IOException while trying to create a filestream to upload to Sharepoint telling me that file2.txt is in use by another process.

The code for the FileSystemWatcher:

```
 public void StartWatcher()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(this.path);

            fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;



            fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(CreateFile);


            try
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    fsw.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All);
                }
            }
            catch
            { }

                fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        }
```

The CreateFile() method called by

```
fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(CreateFile);
```

looks like this:

```
 private void CreateFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            path = String.Format(e.FullPath);
            filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
            Stream fs = File.OpenRead(@path);
            SPAPI spobj = new SPAPI();
            spobj.SPUploader(fs, filename);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

The exception is thrown at

```
Stream fs = File.OpenRead(@path);
```

BUT only when a second file is dragged into the directory after the first one. The strange thing is that not the first file is in use, but the second one that i want to open as a stream. So it's not the stream that is still open and causing the exception. It seems that the second file is in use by the FileSystemWatcher. But why does the first file work just fine but the exception is just thrown when a second file is dragged into the directory?

Comment: `fsw.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All);` - Ditch this. And that abomination of a loop around it including that _empty_ catch.

Comment: File created event raise and trigger immediatly your `CreateFile` new file created into watched directory. However, you drag and drop file into directory does not mean you could use that file, because file probably still copying into directory. If your file size is standard and you know how much time require for copy/create operation, you can add `Thread.Sleep()` before `path = String.Format(e.FullPath);`

Comment: Give it some rest and try again. I've been successful with retrying 3 times after delaying 100ms each in the past.

Comment: It's an expected event. You should expect and handle it (if you got this error - wait a bit and try again).

Comment: Thread.Sleep(100) was the solution... Though i don't understand why i should ditch the try/catch loop and fsw.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All). This keeps my FileSystemWatcher running.

Comment: @Mondblut note that `Thread.Sleep(100)` is not very reliable solution. Try to copy 1GB file to your folder and you'll see how it will fail with `Thread.Sleep(100)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify and use like this. I hope this helps you

```
private void CreateFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    int until = 5;
    int i = 0;
    bool success = false;
    while (!success && i < until)
    {
        try
        {
            path = String.Format(e.FullPath);
            filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
            using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead(@path);)
            {
                SPAPI spobj = new SPAPI();
                spobj.SPUploader(fs, filename);
            }
            success = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, i just added fs.Close() to close the filestream.

Comment: Is there any advantage to just using Thread.Sleep(100) like some other users suggested?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` or `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));` or `Thread.Sleep(1000)` does not matter.

Comment: `try-catch` and `until` parameter gives some flexibility, if your files' size is different and large range. You can edit try count and wait time. For example: if file size is between 1x and 3x, you can use until=3 and waitResponse=t; if file size  is between 2x and 8x, you can use until=4 and waitResponse = 2t. Result of this, task consume time according to file size.